# create a azure function by vscode and Azure Functions Core Tools4.0

Tags: azure-functions

i am learning azure functions by using vscode .
the learning is :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/build-api-azure-functions/4-exercise-create-function-project

but i had error many times.

[2022-09-26T10:46:04.912Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation '8831e24f-fbf6-4d27-9b58-7db5ac87d60a'.
[2022-09-26T10:46:04.913Z] System.Net.Http: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. System.Net.Security:  Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

or it is because of firewall ?

who can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

host.json
delete the source

```
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.*, 4.0.0)"
  }
```